# Rotate only content in after pseudoelement

Tags: css

It's possible to rotate only content?

```
div:after {
    content: "10";
    background-color: fuchsia;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

*Example image:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not possible. But you can utilize both `:before` and `:after` to achieve that:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

div:after{
  content: "10";
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
}

div:before{
  content: "";
  background-color: fuchsia;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```